# Pseudocode algorithm for the product of the first n positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

This is for discrete mathematics:

Write a pseudocode algorithm to compute the product of the first n positive integers. How many multiplications does your algorithm perform?

I tried starting off with n greater than or equal to one. Then I started a for loop like this: for I $\{1,2,...n\}$ then this is where I get stuck as I'm not sure if it should go to n or maybe n-1. I guess I'm just not totally sure how to go about testing for this algorithm.

Comment: This heavily depends on what your class's "pseudocode" looks like. Please help people help you by telling us what you know, what you've tried, and what pseudocode looks like. This might not really even be a math question - it sounds like a coding question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: It's not a coding question because pseudocode is not code -- hence the "pseudo". It is intended for communicating ideas to a human reader rather than for instructing a machine.

Comment: I edited my answer, this version is correct @user5959738

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this pseodocode should work:

Input: a number $n$

Output: $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n$

```
factorial(int number)   
    if (number <= 1)
         return 1;
    else
         return number * factorial(number - 1);
```

Full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class factorial 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     { 
       Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
       int n;
       System.out.println("choose natural number");
       n=input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("facturial::"+factorial(n));
     }
   private static int factorial(int number)
     {
       if (number <= 1)
         return 1;
      else
         return number * factorial(number - 1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Except that this uses `i` twice as nested loop variable, forgets to inititalize `ans` and does not compute $n!$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  I edited, changed the previous answer